# Accept a Dialog with Playwright Sharp

Tags: c#, playwright-sharp

How do I Accept a Dialog like the one below using Playwright Sharp?

[image: Confirm Dialog]

I can't seem to find anything in Playwright Sharp's documentation, however Playwright's (JS) documentation describes how to add an event handler for a dialog:

`page.on('dialog', dialog => dialog.accept());`

Is there a similar way to do this in Playwright Sharp?

Answer (score 1):

page.Dialog triggers dialog events when they appear, it's just a matter of registering an event handler to it as below:

`page.Dialog += (_, x) => x.Dialog.AcceptAsync();`

Answer (score 1):

By default, **Playwright** will dismiss all `(Alert, Popup)` dialogues. To accept the alert, place the below code before the alert trigger code:

```
PageInTest.Dialog += (_, dialog) => dialog.AcceptAsync();
```

This will register the `Page.Dialog` in **Playwright**.

Answer (score 0):

You can preset `page.WaitForEventAsync` for dialog action and timeout, default timeout is 30s.
When dialog activate, that will trigger your preset action and wait for timeout to continue the rest code.

```cs
// Preset dialog react
var dialogTask = page.WaitForEventAsync(PageEvent.Dialog, args =>
{
    args.Dialog.DismissAsync();
    return true;
}, 1000);

// Activate alert dialog
await Page.EvaluateAsync("alert('yo');");

await dialogTask;
```

You can find playwright-sharp page dialog unit test [here](https://github.com/microsoft/playwright-sharp/blob/430533de40/src/PlaywrightSharp.Tests/PageDialogTests.cs#L103) and try to figure out how to use that.

Answer (score 0):

```
--await btnAdd.ClickAsync();
await wlsWorkType.ClickAsync();
```

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Comment: Why are you editing this post so many times? Please try to limit the amount of edits you make to your posts, as it needlessly bumps the question, lest we have to lock it from any further edit.